# Implementig Swiggy like Delivery app's map design

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

Swiggy or any other `On-Demand Services` like delivery app uses a map activity like the image below
[image]           [image]

I planned about the implementation-
1) Add a Places AutoComplete API fragment/ activity
2) Use current location button (indicated in the second screenshot as Google places autocomplete api only provide list of locations but not the current location option
3)Use map to drop a pin at the user's selected place and make it a movable pin so that user can adjust his/her location.

Please guide me if I am going in the right direction and what are the resources to follow

Answer (score 2):

Please try below solution

Add this in your xml file

```
<!--Map-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutMap"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_map"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:text="@string/move_map_to_adjust"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageMarker"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_55sdp"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/map_pin" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Animation Funcation

```
private void circleAnimation() {
        GradientDrawable d = new GradientDrawable();
        d.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        d.setSize(500, 500);
        d.setColor(0x55dddddd);
        d.setStroke(5, Color.BLACK);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                , d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        // Convert the drawable to bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        d.draw(canvas);

        // Radius of the circle
        final int radius = 20;

        // Add the circle to the map
        final GroundOverlay circle = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .position(mMap.getCameraPosition().target, 2 * radius).image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));

        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
        valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        valueAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        valueAnimator.setIntValues(0, radius);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(2000);
        valueAnimator.setEvaluator(new IntEvaluator());
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                float animatedFraction = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                circle.setDimensions(animatedFraction * radius * 2);
            }
        });

        valueAnimator.start();
    }
```

Add this code in your **onMapReady**

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                mMap.clear();
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                latLng = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                currLat = latLng.latitude;
                currLong = latLng.longitude;
                Log.e(TAG, "currLat: " + currLat);
                Log.e(TAG, "currLong: " + currLong);
                mMap.clear();
                circleAnimation();
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.